# is *(1 + &foo) the same as *(&foo + 1) in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c

Is this:

```
*(1 + &foo)
```

the same as this?

```
*(&foo + 1)
```

'+' and '&' have the same precedence and they are evaluated right-to-left. However you can't interpret the second case like this:

```
*(&(foo + 1))
```

...because you can only use '&' with an l-value (it won't even compile if you write it like that). So will it be garbage? Or will it safely figure out what you meant?

Comment: The binary `+` (which you're using here) and the address operator `&` do *not* have the same precedence.

Comment: Also, the order of evaluation is unspecified. The binary operators *group* (associate) *left-to-right*, but again that doesn't matter here since all the operators are different precedence. It sounds like you were looking at the unary operators.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent (the third one obviously is not).

The *unary* `&` operator has higher precedence than the *binary* `+` operator (as all unary operators do), so `&foo + 1` parses as `(&foo) + 1`. What you are thinking of when you say they have the same precedence is the *unary* `+` operator (which is a different operator) [has the same precedence as](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_operators#Operator_precedence) unary `&`.

Comment: The binary & operator has a much lower precedence than +.

Comment: I think he/she is thinking of the *unary* `+` operator, which does have the same precedence as *unary* `&`.

Comment: Well that was easy! Thanks for a quick and accurate solution.

Comment: In C, they're the same because `+` is commutative. In C++, you can define your own operators and semantic interpretation becomes much more complex. This is *one* of the reasons why C++ is many orders of magnitude more evil than C.

Comment: You have to regard (binary) `+` as commutative in C because you don't know the order of evaluation of the arguments anyway, and the base mathematical operation itself is commutative.

Comment: It is due to the fact that these are the same that makes `a[1]` the same as `1[a]` for raw arrays.

Comment: @Donal, one could argue that in C++ they had better be the same. Generally defining operator overloads that completely defy the usual meanings of the operators in question is a poor idea. But it is certainly possible to exchange the meanings of `+` and `*` for fun and profit!

Comment: there are occasions where it makes sense to have non-commutative operations e.g. matrix multiplication or string concatenation

Comment: @RBerteig: As @jk points out, there may well be good reasons for not making them the same, and there's certainly no *guarantee* of it. This is very different from C, an area where the two languages have diverged quite strongly. (I prefer the C approach, but I recognize that this is an area where programmers disagree.)

Comment: @Donal, agreed. I'm just pointing out that the names of operators form a kind of contract with the user. They must continue to make sense, in the context of that contract. Using `*` as a non-commutative matrix multiply as a good example of accepting both that contract and the limitations that are imposed. Ditto for `+` as string concatenate. But it is possible to wander really far into the weeds with the best of intentions...

Comment: @Donal very good observation -- returning to the original question (I won't go into operator overloading etc). I interpreted the question as I think it was intended -- basically "does &foo + 1 mean (&foo) + 1 or &(foo + 1)?" But I didn't look at the commutativity of + in C. Even without operator overloading, this isn't strictly true -- on x86 machines, floating point calculations are usually 80-bit but drop down to 64-bit when the compiler runs out of registers; therefore, the order of the computation can change the precision in rare cases. But, for all practical purposes, yes.

Comment: Also, [fun things you see in Google when you're trying to find this out](http://mattblr.tumblr.com/post/2969914346/o-kay-i-was-going-to-type-is-floating-point).

Comment: @mgiuca: You're getting mixed up with associativity, which does matter. Commutativity doesn't, precisely because you don't know what order the operations will be listed in at the low level. (C simply does not give that guarantee, nor does C++ when using the standard arithmetic operators.)

Comment: @Donal Fellows No I tried not to get those mixed up :) It is easy to come up with a floating-point example where associativity changes the outcome. For commutativity (swapping expression order around an operator), it will almost always give the same result, BUT there are ways to give a different result. Swapping the operands changes the order in which the CPU calculates things, which can result in different register spilling and therefore different numbers of bits available in the computation.

Comment: @mgiuca: If you're working at that level, you don't really want to be using either C or C++ as they don't really give you the control you need. OTOH, if you've got problems from that then you've also likely got algorithmic stability problems (either you already know this in depth, or you should talk to a numerical analyst specializing in dealing with the effects of floating point on algorithms).

Comment: @Donal Fellows What "level" am I working at? Understanding the effects of inaccuracy on floating-point computations is something which everybody needs to know, at any "level", in any language. The instability of associativity is an important consideration; the instability of commutativity is much less likely to affect anyone but still something worth knowing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same.   Note that binary `+` has a *lower* precedence than `&`.  You're probably thinking of *unary* `+`.

Comment: @aaa It's the wrong colour - that guy's *obviously* a trustworthy babysitter.

Answer (score 1):

As shown on [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence), `&` and `+` only have the same precedence when interpreting `+` as a unary operator -- for example, as in `a - +b`.

When interpreting `+` as a binary operator, it has a lower precedence than `&`, and so the second case will be interpreted as `*((&foo) + 1)` rather than `*(&(foo + 1))`.